# Assigning 'self' when creating custom UITableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to load a nib for a custom `UITableViewCell` in my Objective-C code I am doing this

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"RouteCell" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nibArray firstObject];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I try to implement this method in Swift I cannot find a way to 'translate' the `self = [nibArray firstObject]`

Here is my Swift implementation

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {

    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    var nibArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("RouteCell", owner: self, options: nil)
    self = nibArray.first

}
```

On the last line I get an error of `Cannot assign self in a method`. How can I do this assignment in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`init` methods in swift is very different from their counterpart in obj-c. You should read the Apple doc here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_318

`self` cannot be overridden in swift.

To use a custom xib for your cell, you can consider using an alternative approach. It is an idea:

```
   var nipName=UINib(nibName: "RouteCell", bundle:nil)

   self.tableView.registerNib(nipName, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```